# Error when run my programe using GPDomain object

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

I have this library:

```
Microsoft.GroupPolicy;
```

And this code:

```
GPDomain domain = new GPDomain("MyDomain");
Console.WriteLine(domain.DomainName);
```

I get this message error when I run the code:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.GroupPolicy.ServerAdminTools.GpmgmtLib, 
Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its 
dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Any idea on how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

missing Microsoft.GroupPolicy.ServerAdminTools.GpmgmtLib.dll

[Installing the GPMC Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff182374%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

and try this on win8
 [Install the GPMC](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725932.aspx#BKMK_UI)

Comment: How can this be helpful? It's exactly what the error message is saying.

Comment: but my OS Windows 8 the table is not contain solution to Win 8

Comment: I found the answer very helpful since I didn't know the GPMC Class Library included the Microsoft.GroupPolicy.ServerAdminTools.Gpmgmtlib.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a very old question, but a google search brings you here and there isn't a lot of information about this that I could find elsewhere.

As stated in a previous answer you will need to install the GPMC Class Library. There is a download for Windows 7 and earlier machines, but for Windows 8 and newer it can be installed as an optional Windows feature in Settings/Control Panel. Look for "RSAT: Group Policy Management Tools".

Other answers on Stack Overflow mention needing to link Microsoft.GroupPolicy.Management.dll from `%windir%`/Microsoft.NET/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.GroupPolicy.Management, but certain classes require additional libraries.

GPDomain requires Microsoft.GroupPolicy.ServerAdminTools.GpmgmtLib from `%windir%`\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_`<arch>`\Microsoft.GroupPolicy.ServerAdminTools.GpmgmtLib.

Some other classes require Microsoft.GroupPolicy.Management.Interop, also found in the GAC_`<arch>` folder.